# JavaScript Execute Object.entries() from a value

Tags: javascript, function, object

I need to create a function which creates combo boxes from an json object. I can not get

```
"use strict"

let vars = {
  kagit: {
    "ABR": 50,
    "Krome 230 gr": 230,
    "Krome 300 gr": 300,
    "Krome 350 gr": 350,
    "Fantezi": 6,
    "Kraft": 5,
    "1. Hamur": 4
  },
 ebat: {
  "50x70 cm": 5,
  "90x126 cm": 76
 }
}
```

As you see from the function I use object.entries() but when I try to execute the function I can not put the parameter which returned from function execution.

```
function comboBox(comboValue) {

  let getValue = comboValue;

  let comboOption = document.querySelector('.' + getValue);

  let defaultOption = document.createElement('option');
  defaultOption.text = 'Lütfen Seçiniz';

  comboOption.add(defaultOption);
  comboOption.selectedIndex = 0;

  let objEnt = "vars." + getValue;

  let option;
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(objEnt)) {
      option = document.createElement('option');
      option.text = key;
      option.value = value;
      comboOption.add(option);
    }
    return;
}
comboBox("kagit");
```

Comment: `let objEnt = "vars." + getValue;` Then `objEnt` is a *string*, not an object...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't pass a string to `Object.Entries`. Pass the object, instead:

```js
let vars = {
  kagit: { "ABR": 50, "Krome 230 gr": 230, "Krome 300 gr": 300, "Krome 350 gr": 350, "Fantezi": 6, "Kraft": 5, "1. Hamur": 4 },
  ebat: { "50x70 cm": 5, "90x126 cm": 76 }
}

function comboBox(comboValue) {
  // Get the chosen value from the `vars` global;
  let objEnt = vars[comboValue];

  // Now get this value's entries
  let entries = Object.entries(objEnt);

  console.log(entries)
}

comboBox("kagit");
```